# AngularJS initialize controller module

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to seperate my WebApp in different modules for directives, services, controllers etc. just like angular-seed. Somehow the controllers defined in `controllers.js` don't seem to work.

```
<ul class="menu" ng-controller="MenuController">
    <li>{{hello}}</li>
</ul>
```

In `app.js` I defined the global App module with it's submodules.

```
// Declare app level module which depends on filters, and services
angular.module('myApp', [
    'myApp.filters',
    'myApp.services',
    'myApp.directives',
    'myApp.controllers'
]);
```

And in `controllers.js` I tried to define a controller, that does not load. When the page get rendered I just see `{{hello}}`.

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', []).
  controller('MenuController', function($scope) {
     $scope.hello = "world"; 
  });
```

How do I attach the controllers to their template counterparts?

Comment: Did you reference the controller script in your index.html?

Comment: @stefchri Yes, I did. I'm sure it's loaded (Angular aswell). Because when I create the controller globally in `controllers.js`: `function MenuController($scope){ $scope.hello = "world"; }` it works..

Comment: Ensure that controller.js is loaded `before` app.js

Comment: @KhanhTO Thanks, that did the trick. If you'd make it an answers, I'd accept it.

Comment: That's ok. Just a small mistake, I will not post an answer

Comment: Please do, otherwise the question will remain unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because the other modules aren't defined. Modifying the myApp module like below works:

```
angular.module('myApp', [

    'myApp.controllers'
]);
```

http://jsbin.com/osOQOYag/2/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

It seems like angular-seed has the following order of scripts in their `/app/index.html`:

```
<script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/services.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/filters.js"></script>
<script src="js/directives.js"></script>
```

As @KhanhTO pointed out in the comments, `app.js` should be called last.